# How to get session id in spring-data-rest

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-data-rest, postman

I am newbie to spring-data-rest. Here I am developing a shopping cart application using spring-data-rest. I need to get the session id in response to the POST request that I made in postman client. So, when I post cart details from POSTMAN client in response I am getting empty page which indicated success. Instead of that I need to get the session id. How can I get session id for that cart, so that I can make a direct call to that cart using session id what I get in response?

Here is my cart bean class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cart", catalog="db_sports" )
// Define named queries here
@NamedQueries ( {
@NamedQuery ( name="Cart.countAll", query="SELECT COUNT(x) FROM Cart x" )
} )

@Component
@Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value="session")
public class Cart implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false)
    private Integer    id           ;
    private Date       date         ;

   //----------------------------------------------------------------------
   // ENTITY LINKS ( RELATIONSHIP )
   //----------------------------------------------------------------------
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="tenant_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private Tenant tenant      ;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="cart", targetEntity=CartItem.class)
private List<CartItem> listOfCartItem;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_phoneno", referencedColumnName="phoneno")
private User user        ;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="cart", targetEntity=Invoice.class)
private List<Invoice> listOfInvoice;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// CONSTRUCTOR(S)
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public Cart()
{
    super();
}


//to string method
   //setters and getters
    }
```

Can someone help me how can I get session id for the cart?

Thanks in advance.